# Alternate of Authentication create trigger in 2nd Gen - Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to trigger a function when a user is created in Firebase Authentication, and I wrote this

```js
const {onCreate} = require("firebase-functions/v2/auth");

exports.removeInvite = onCreate(async (user) => {
  return await myInviteFunctions.removeInvite(FieldValue, firestoreDB, user);
});
```

Any alternate code for this in **2nd Gen**, as recent updates of `firebase-tools` are causing the issue on this line and giving the following errors as *coding issues*
[image]

and with `--debug` the error is
[image]

Comment: [Auth v2 functions aren't implemented yet](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1383) (at time of writing), but you can mix v1 and v2 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @samthecodingman! Auth v2 functions aren't implemented yet. So I mix it with v1

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); // v1

exports.removeInvite = functions.auth.user()onCreate(async (user) => {
  return await myInviteFunctions.removeInvite(FieldValue, firestoreDB, user);
});
```